# NextJS - FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory when building application

Tags: node.js, npm, ansible, next.js, heap-memory

I've developed a medium sized NextJS application and I'm getting **"FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory"** when the **"npm run build"** command is run on an AWS EC2 instance with Ansible. I have no issues building the application on my local machine and even on the EC2 instance. On top of that, the first time Ansible executes the build (when the EC2 instance is first created), everything works smoothly as well. It's only with subsequent builds (redeployments to an existing machine) that this issue occurs.

The error I get is:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[22024:0000022B07BF7840]      268 ms: Scavenge 10.5 (15.5) -> 8.5 (16.5) MB, 3.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure 
[22024:0000022B07BF7840]      324 ms: Scavenge 11.6 (24.5) -> 9.5 (25.5) MB, 6.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure 
[22024:0000022B07BF7840]      402 ms: Scavenge 16.4 (25.5) -> 11.8 (26.0) MB, 16.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: 00007FF6D3C8481F 
 2: 00007FF6D3C27F26 
 3: 00007FF6D3C28E26 
 4: 00007FF6D45022EE 
 5: 00007FF6D44E70BD 
 6: 00007FF6D3F77790 
 7: 00007FF6D3F943CA 
 8: 00007FF6D484C9E5 
 9: 00007FF6D482E8C4 
10: 00007FF6D48D33EF 
11: 00007FF6D48D31BF 
12: 00007FF6D48DD4B7 
13: 00007FF6D44545C0 
14: 00007FF6D4451A66 
15: 00007FF6D40F4D1A 
16: 00007FF6D458B1AD 
 1: 00007FF6D3C8481F 
17: 00007FF6D452381E 
 2: 00007FF6D3C27F26 
 3: 00007FF6D3C28E26 
 4: 00007FF6D45022EE 
 5: 00007FF6D44E70BD 
 6: 00007FF6D3F77790 
 7: 00007FF6D3F943CA 
 8: 00007FF6D489A2B8 
 9: 00007FF6D488D55B 
10: 00007FF6D488D8BC 
11: 00007FF6D48D37A6 
12: 00007FF6D48D31BF 
18: 000002A351F138B2 
 1: 00007FF6D3C8481npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221226505
npm ERR! job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221226505
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\svc.gridsub_dev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-09T00_02_04_411Z-debug.log
```

And here is the output in the log file that's referenced at the end there:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.13
3 info using node@v14.17.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~prebuild: job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~build: job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0
7 warn lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is F:\Bin\JobAnalyticsDashboard\FrontEnd\node.exe but npm is using C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
8 verbose lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;F:\Bin\JobAnalyticsDashboard\FrontEnd\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\svc.gridsub_dev\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\svc.gridsub_dev\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\svc.gridsub_dev\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~build: CWD: F:\Bin\JobAnalyticsDashboard\FrontEnd
11 silly lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next build' ]
12 silly lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 3221226505  signal: null
13 info lifecycle job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0 build: `next build`
14 verbose stack Exit status 3221226505
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
15 verbose pkgid job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0
16 verbose cwd F:\Bin\JobAnalyticsDashboard\FrontEnd
17 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
18 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
19 verbose node v14.17.1
20 verbose npm  v6.14.13
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 3221226505
23 error job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0 build: `next build`
23 error Exit status 3221226505
24 error Failed at the job-analytics-dashboard@0.1.0 build script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 3221226505, true ]
```

For reference, my NPM build consumes at most a little over a GB of ram.

I've done a lot of research trying to fix this issue, and the main solution that comes up is using the **--max-old-space-size** flag to increase the amount of memory allocated to Node. I've upped this value to **16GB** and still no luck. The machine I'm working with has 32GB so I have room to work with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today.
after checking available ways, it **fixes** by doing the below actions.

1. **invalidate the cache** and **restart** IDE
2. close some applications which are **eating** memory and **disk**